# CXF web service works correctly, but I can't get its wsdl from the cxf web site

Tags: java, cxf

I have a Java project in which I a writing the pom.xml, beans.xml and wsdl file and generating the code using Maven. Then, after completing the code, I am able to compile and deploy my web service in my server that uses Apache Fuse/CXF.

If I call this web service using soapUI, it works correctly, giving me the expected answer.

If I try to access the wsdl file in this url http://:8181/cxf/ I can see all the deployed services, but if I try to click in the link to get the WSDL, I am redirected to a URL with this format: http://:8181/Services/myService?wsdl when the correct should be http://:8181/**cxf/** Services/myService?wsdl

I have 3 projects in which this issue happens. I have also 1 project in which this issue doesn't happen.
I've been comparing the solutions using winmerge but I could not find any difference that would explain this issue.

Do you know what property of what file define this link?

thank you,
Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like CXF needed some hours to do it right. When I got back to work this morning, it was working :)